# Make Webpacker compile/serve a specific pack only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, webpacker

Is there a way to tell Webpacker to compile/serve only a specific pack? For example, we have two pack applications under `app/javascript/packs`, which are called `challenge` and `app`.

While using `bundle exec rails webpacker:compile` or `bin/webpack-dev-server` is there a way to send a parameter to specify if I want to compile/serve only one of these packs?

```
rails-7
webpacker (5.4.3)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Webpacker doesn't make the call here. It's up to your view to dictate which is used via the stylesheet and javascript helper methods.

Comment: @tadman I understand that for compiling the application, but is it the same for the `bin/webpack-dev-server`?

Comment: The server only serves what's requested, and the request is driven by the view/layout.